# How to install kubernetes on multiple machines simultaneously?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, devops

I have n number of machines, how can I check if kubernetes is installed on the machine or not ,if its not installed how to setup kubernetes cluster on multiple machines simultaneously? (trying to automate kubernetes installation on multiple machines)
What tools/technology can be used for this?

Comment: ansible might be your best option

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Ansible, use [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray), it allows to install, expand and upgrade production grade clusters.